# Old JavaScript still executing, after cache clear

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, magento, google-chrome-devtools

I've been updating a JavaScript file and pushing each change to the sites server. After every push I have cleared my local cache files and the servers cached files (Magento Store).

My issue is that the old JavaScript is still being run, even though the source in chrome inspector shows the new JavaScript.

Chrome sources and console:
[core.js, console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlCiE.png)

Line 126 is where the code was deleted from.

Comment: Can you provide the script url ?

Comment: Afraid not, It's a clients site so we can't do that kind of thing.

Comment: then try visiting the url to view the script and (in a new tab) open the url with any param at the end (ex: [url]?x=1). you can compare the script in the new window and tell if your changes appear in it.
then you can open the script url in the incognito mode and if you see your changes then it is the browser

Comment: Have done, the two scripts are the same. They both don't have the code I removed in them but the error is still showing in the console.

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />